# Optimizing the sample size: number of individuals versus trials per individual

Tags: estimation, optimization, loss-functions

Given that I have $C$ to spend on my experiment, what is the optimal number of individuals $n$ of my experiment?

Say that I want to estimate the mean $\mu$ of distribution of individuals

$$X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$$

and I can sample several values from each individual which is distributed as

$$Y_{ij} \sim N(X_{i}, \tau)$$

Say that

- the costs of recruiting an individual are $a$
- and the cost of obtaining a sample are $b$

For example, when we sample Alice, Bob and Carol twice each and Eve once, then we sampled 4 persons 7 times and the cost will be $4a+7b$. (So sampling the same person another time only costs $b$ whereas sampling a new person will cost $a+b$)

then what is the ideal number of individuals $n$ and samples $k$, within the costs $C$ to get the highest precision of estimate (in terms of lowest variance).

Let's assume that we know $\sigma$ and $\tau$. But $\mu$, which we want to estimate, is unknown.

Let's assume that we use a [weighted least squares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares) to estimate $\mu$. And I consider optimal to be the lowest standard error of the estimate (which needs to be unbiased).

---

Motivations for this question are

[How to fix the problem in this XKCD comic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606507/)

[Balancing effect of sample size and amount of trials on power](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562744/)

Comment: Just to clarify, if I sample Alice, Bob and Carol twice each and Eve once, I will pay $3a + a + (2\cdot 3)b + b$?

Comment: I'm not going to provide a complete answer, I just tell you that as far as I can see, the variance of the overall mean (assuming that your notation uses unsquared standard deviations) will be $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{\tau^2}{kn}$. Obviously $k\to\infty$ will reduce the second term to 0, but increasing $n$ is the only way to get the first part down (and this will reduce the second part as well of course). I haven't checked whether the plain mean is the optimal estimator though. I am however sure that no estimator can get the variance to zero for fixed $n$ and $k\to\infty$.

Comment: For $k=1$ the plain mean achieves $\frac{\sigma^2+\tau^2}{n}$ and this is optimal. For fixed $n$ and $k\to\infty$ there is no way to do better than $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ as this would assume we know the $X_i$ precisely, so whatever optimal GLS estimator will be between these. $n\to\infty$ will reduce the variance to zero in all cases, $k\to\infty$ never will. (Investing a certain amount into $k$ may be OK if $\tau^2>\sigma^2$.)

Comment: I agree with @ChristianHennig (+1) Intuitively, small $k$ and high $n$ should be a better solution than high $k$ and low $n$. But i think this is where the costs come into play (that's why I asked) if $a >> b$ for example we accrue a lot of cost very quickly.

Comment: @usεr11852 if you sample 3 people and sample 2+2+1=5 times, then you will pay $3a+5b$. Obviously inreasing $n$ is better but it comes at a higher cost because it is not just adding another sample, but also adding an additional individual on the pool of sampled individuals.

Comment: OK. (That's why I wrote in my example too...)

Comment: I am bad enough at math and good enough at computer programming that I would want to simulate this. Loop over a grid of $n$ and $k$ values, generate some number (20?) of datasets at each `(n,k)` pair, fit your model on each, and compute the sample standard deviation of your estimate-of-interest over all those models. If you want to get really fancy, use the wide variety of techniques from machine learning for the purpose of computing optimal parameters for an expensive function (as in hyperparameter search). Look up "Bayesian optimization" and "black-box optimization", eg `hyperopt` in Python.

Comment: Note that the above assumes that every individual is tested the same number of times. You could probably develop other more sophisticated schemes where you sample an individual until some threshold of information or confidence is reached. It might be worth looking up "multi-armed bandit" algorithms for this kind of thing. However I don't know much about how they work, and haven't used them myself, as I have happily avoided "A/B testing" in my career so far.

Comment: @shadowtalker I believe that a computation like that might work (I wouldn't use simulations though, but instead apply a some sort of formula like the one presented by Christian Hennig).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: I think for a fixed $\sigma$ and $\tau$ the variance increases monotonically and exponentially as $n$ is decreased. Coupling that with fixed costs for $a$ and $b$ we just want the maximal $n$ we can get. This aligns with what Christian H said about the "plain mean" being the optimal one.

Comment: @usεr11852 I agree that a plain mean is gonna be optimal (or more precisely we have a sample of $r$ people being sampled $i$ times and $q$ people being sampled $i+1$ times, and we could slightly improve on the plain mean, but that is just a technical issue). But, the main issue is the number of people that are optimal.

Comment: "the maximal $n$ we can get" I follow the intuition, but I imagine that this brakes down when $\sigma$ is much smaller than $\tau$. In the extreme case, if $\sigma =0$, then increasing $n$ doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: Also I think the ratio $\frac{\sigma}{\tau}$ is going to be very helpful to have. As soon as $\tau > \sigma$ the utility of multiple samples decreases significantly.

Comment: @usεr11852 when $\sigma = 0$ then our samples $Y_{ij}$ might still have some error because of $\tau$.

Answer (score 6):

The mean per individual will be distributed as

$$\bar{Y}_i = \frac{1}{n_i} \sum_{j = 1}^{n_i} Y_{ij} \sim N\left(\mu, \sigma^2 + \tau^2/n_i\right)$$

where $n_i \geq 1$ are the number of observations for individual $i$ (we need at least 1 measurement for a participant).

The estimate will be

$$\hat{\mu} = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i \bar{Y}_i$$

with $$w_i =  \frac{(\sigma^2 + \tau^2/n_i)^{-1}}{ \sum_{l=1}^n (\sigma^2 + \tau^2/n_l)^{-1}} $$

and the variance will be

$$\text{VAR}(\hat{\mu}) = \frac{1}{\sum_{l=i}^n (\sigma^2 + \tau^2/n_i)^{-1}} \approx \frac{\sigma^2}{n }+ \frac{\tau^2}{ \sum n_i} =  \frac{\sigma^2}{n }+ \frac{\tau^2}{ m} $$

The approximate is exactly true when the $n_i$ are all the same. And we defined $m =  \sum n_i$.

The variance decreases when we increase $n$ or when we increase $m$. With the changes being

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial n}  \text{VAR}(\hat{\mu}) =  - \frac{\sigma^2}{n^2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}  \text{VAR}(\hat{\mu}) =  - \frac{\tau^2}{m^2} \\$$

and the optimum will occur when the amount of observations per individual follows the ratio

$$\frac{m}{n} = \frac{\tau\sqrt{a}}{\sigma\sqrt{b}}$$

and there is also the limit $\frac{m}{n} > 1$ because we need at minimum one observation per individual.

Comment: The analysis is a bit approximate since I assume a continuous change in $m$ but in reality this will occur in discrete steps, and in addition not all individuals need to have exactly equal $n_i$ trials per individual.