# Determination of sample size vs. repeated measurements in experimental design

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, sample-size, statistical-power, paired-data

*NOTE: Revised question following suggestions from others. Thank you for taking the time to help me refine this question to make it answerable!*

### Background

I want to compare the performance of two versions of a device:  `V1` and `V2`. I have done two pilot studies. I used a linear mixed-effect model and found 100% of my variance is attributable to measurement error. This matches my expectations, but how do I deal with it?

The performance of the device is measured as the input force required to do some work on a `test subject` in a standardized test. Each device is attached to a standard test rig which applies the input force in the same way every time. The input force is applied to the device and the device translates this into an output force which stuffs the `test subject` into a hole.  The `test subject` is essentially a bag filled with viscous fluid.

There is an element of randomness in the way the fluid moves and the bag wrinkles as it is pushed. These random events *do* affect the input force needed to push the bag through the hole. This can be expressed as $x^{*} = x+\Delta$.  Where,  $x$ represents the theoretical input force required if there were no fluid movement or bag wrinkling, and $\Delta$ represents the (random) additional force required to overcome these dynamic effects. I can only measure $x^{*}$ - there is no way to measure $x$.  Measurement of $x^{*}$ is continuous.

To compare performance, I want to test:
$H_{0}: x_{V2}^{*} \ngtr  x_{V1}^{*}$
$H_{A}: x_{V2}^{*} > x_{V1}^{*}$

The minimum difference between groups that I want to be able to detect is 1.5 units of input force.

*Note that I have plenty of `V2` devices available to test and do pilot studies on. I have 10 `V1` devices, but they are out of production so it's difficult and expensive to obtain more (long lead time and high cost associated with setting up and running more). I may be able to scrape together another 5 or so `V1` devices from other sources, but I don't know for sure. Testing is non-destructive and it's fairly easy to get multiple repeat measures off a single device.*

### What I've done

I did a pilot study on 10 `V2` devices and I measured the input force on 2 separate but identical `test subjects` with 2 repeat measures per combination (total of 40 runs). Below are the results from trying to fit this to a linear mixed effects model in Minitab: ≈90% variance is attributed to error, ≈10% is attributed to the test subject, and 0% is attributed to the device. This generally matches my expectations because 1) the principles of operation of the device and the test rig do not suggest there would be much (if any) detectable difference between devices; 2) I expect randomness (error) due to random factor $\Delta$ mentioned above. I actually suspect the ≈10% attributed to test sample is an artifact of not having enough repeat measures (labeled replicate in the table). I am doing a second pilot study to investigate this further.

| Factor | Type | Levels | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device | Random | 10 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 |
| Test Subject | Random | 2 | A,C |

| Source | Variance | % of Total | SE Var | Z-Value | P-Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device | 0.00000 | 0.00% | * | * | * |
| Test Subject | 0.160500 | 10.65% | 0.322545 | 0.497604 | 0.309 |
| Device*Test Subject | 0.000000 | 0.00% | * | * | * |
| Error | 1.346250 | 89.35% | 0.308851 | 4.358899 | 0.000 |
| Total | 1.506750 |  |  |  |  |
| -2 Log Likelihood = 127.180857 |  |  |  |  |  |

| S | R-sq | R-sq(Adj.) | AICc | BIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.16028 | 7.46% | 7.46% | 136.36 | 141.84 |

Here is the data from the Pilot Study:

| RunOrder | Device | Test Subject | Replicate | Helper | Helper2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | A | 1 | A.1 | 5.A.1 | 8.5 |
| 2 | 9 | C | 1 | C.1 | 9.C.1 | 9.2 |
| 3 | 6 | C | 1 | C.1 | 6.C.1 | 9.8 |
| 4 | 7 | A | 1 | A.1 | 7.A.1 | 7.6 |
| 5 | 7 | C | 1 | C.1 | 7.C.1 | 6.6 |
| 6 | 2 | A | 1 | A.1 | 2.A.1 | 8.2 |
| 7 | 1 | C | 1 | C.1 | 1.C.1 | 8.4 |
| 8 | 5 | C | 1 | C.1 | 5.C.1 | 7.3 |
| 9 | 4 | A | 1 | A.1 | 4.A.1 | 8 |
| 10 | 3 | A | 1 | A.1 | 3.A.1 | 7.1 |
| 11 | 4 | C | 1 | C.1 | 4.C.1 | 9.4 |
| 12 | 5 | C | 2 | C.2 | 5.C.2 | 9.7 |
| 13 | 6 | A | 1 | A.1 | 6.A.1 | 5.9 |
| 14 | 8 | A | 1 | A.1 | 8.A.1 | 9.5 |
| 15 | 2 | C | 1 | C.1 | 2.C.1 | 7.1 |
| 16 | 10 | A | 1 | A.1 | 10.A.1 | 7.8 |
| 17 | 3 | C | 1 | C.1 | 3.C.1 | 7.5 |
| 18 | 2 | C | 2 | C.2 | 2.C.2 | 7.6 |
| 19 | 5 | A | 2 | A.2 | 5.A.2 | 6.8 |
| 20 | 8 | C | 1 | C.1 | 8.C.1 | 8.6 |
| 21 | 8 | C | 2 | C.2 | 8.C.2 | 8.3 |
| 22 | 3 | C | 2 | C.2 | 3.C.2 | 10.3 |
| 23 | 7 | A | 2 | A.2 | 7.A.2 | 5.3 |
| 24 | 9 | A | 1 | A.1 | 9.A.1 | 8.5 |
| 25 | 9 | C | 2 | C.2 | 9.C.2 | 8.6 |
| 26 | 1 | C | 2 | C.2 | 1.C.2 | 8.6 |
| 27 | 10 | A | 2 | A.2 | 10.A.2 | 6.9 |
| 28 | 1 | A | 1 | A.1 | 1.A.1 | 6.3 |
| 29 | 10 | C | 1 | C.1 | 10.C.1 | 6.8 |
| 30 | 4 | C | 2 | C.2 | 4.C.2 | 6.4 |
| 31 | 6 | A | 2 | A.2 | 6.A.2 | 7.5 |
| 32 | 8 | A | 2 | A.2 | 8.A.2 | 5.6 |
| 33 | 10 | C | 2 | C.2 | 10.C.2 | 6.1 |
| 34 | 9 | A | 2 | A.2 | 9.A.2 | 7.4 |
| 35 | 7 | C | 2 | C.2 | 7.C.2 | 7.4 |
| 36 | 6 | C | 2 | C.2 | 6.C.2 | 7.8 |
| 37 | 4 | A | 2 | A.2 | 4.A.2 | 7.7 |
| 38 | 2 | A | 2 | A.2 | 2.A.2 | 8.7 |
| 39 | 1 | A | 2 | A.2 | 1.A.2 | 8.3 |
| 40 | 3 | A | 2 | A.2 | 3.A.2 | 6.4 |

## Questions I have

### Question 1 - How to handle the measurement error? Are repeat measures the best way?

How do I deal with this measurement error? It seems to me the best way to deal with this inherent randomness would be to take repeat measures for each device. Is that an appropriate and valid approach? Is it the right approach?

### Question 2 - How many repeat measures are needed?

Assuming repeat measures are an appropriate way to deal with this variability, how do I decide how many repeat measures are needed? i.e., is 2 enough? 3? 5? 10? How can determine this?

### Second Pilot Study

One of my test subjects was damaged, so I had to switch to another pair of test subjects. These have a larger volume, which makes the absolute values in this test higher than the previous test. I don't really care about absolute values, I just want to be able to compare my two groups.

Results from LMM:

| Factor | Type | Levels | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device | Random | 10 | 1,2 |
| Test Subject | Random | 2 | A,C |

| Source | Variance | % of Total | SE Var | Z-Value | P-Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device | 0.00000 | 0.00% | * | * | * |
| Test Subject | 0.00000 | 0.00% | * | * | * |
| Device*Test Subject | 0.00000 | 0.00% | * | * | * |
| Error | 1.345297 | 100.00% | 0.247689 | 5.431390 | 0.000 |
| Total | 1.345297 |  |  |  |  |
| -2 Log Likelihood = 189.029348 |  |  |  |  |  |

| S | R-sq | R-sq(Adj.) | AICc | BIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.15987 | 0.00% | 0.00% | 197.77 | 205.34 |

Data:

| StdOrder | RunOrder | Device | Test Subject | Replicate | Helper | Helper2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | B | 1 | B.1 | 2.B.1 | 10.7 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | B | 1 | B.1 | 1.B.1 | 11.7 |
| 58 | 3 | 1 | B | 2 | B.2 | 1.B.2 | 10.2 |
| 60 | 4 | 2 | B | 2 | B.2 | 2.B.2 | 11.5 |
| 47 | 5 | 2 | A | 1 | A.1 | 2.A.1 | 11.6 |
| 45 | 6 | 1 | A | 1 | A.1 | 1.A.1 | 10.7 |
| 13 | 7 | 1 | A | 2 | A.2 | 1.A.2 | 9.7 |
| 15 | 8 | 2 | A | 2 | A.2 | 2.A.2 | 10.6 |
| 1 | 9 | 1 | A | 3 | A.3 | 1.A.3 | 10.7 |
| 3 | 10 | 2 | A | 3 | A.3 | 2.A.3 | 9.9 |
| 23 | 11 | 2 | A | 4 | A.4 | 2.A.4 | 10 |
| 21 | 12 | 1 | A | 4 | A.4 | 1.A.4 | 11.9 |
| 25 | 13 | 1 | A | 5 | A.5 | 1.A.5 | 10 |
| 27 | 14 | 2 | A | 5 | A.5 | 2.A.5 | 11.3 |
| 55 | 15 | 2 | A | 6 | A.6 | 2.A.6 | 10.4 |
| 53 | 16 | 1 | A | 6 | A.6 | 1.A.6 | 10.5 |
| 20 | 17 | 2 | B | 3 | B.3 | 2.B.3 | 10.1 |
| 18 | 18 | 1 | B | 3 | B.3 | 1.B.3 | 10.9 |
| 24 | 19 | 2 | B | 4 | B.4 | 2.B.4 | 8.9 |
| 22 | 20 | 1 | B | 4 | B.4 | 1.B.4 | 11.4 |
| 33 | 21 | 1 | A | 7 | A.7 | 1.A.7 | 9 |
| 35 | 22 | 2 | A | 7 | A.7 | 2.A.7 | 11.2 |
| 49 | 23 | 1 | A | 8 | A.8 | 1.A.8 | 10.9 |
| 51 | 24 | 2 | A | 8 | A.8 | 2.A.8 | 8.3 |
| 10 | 25 | 1 | B | 5 | B.5 | 1.B.5 | 10.3 |
| 12 | 26 | 2 | B | 5 | B.5 | 2.B.5 | 11.5 |
| 43 | 27 | 2 | A | 9 | A.9 | 2.A.9 | 9.2 |
| 41 | 28 | 1 | A | 9 | A.9 | 1.A.9 | 9.6 |
| 52 | 29 | 2 | B | 6 | B.6 | 2.B.6 | 9.5 |
| 50 | 30 | 1 | B | 6 | B.6 | 1.B.6 | 9.8 |
| 40 | 31 | 2 | B | 7 | B.7 | 2.B.7 | 12.1 |
| 38 | 32 | 1 | B | 7 | B.7 | 1.B.7 | 9.7 |
| 56 | 33 | 2 | B | 8 | B.8 | 2.B.8 | 10.7 |
| 54 | 34 | 1 | B | 8 | B.8 | 1.B.8 | 10.2 |
| 29 | 35 | 1 | A | 10 | A.10 | 1.A.10 | 11.8 |
| 31 | 36 | 2 | A | 10 | A.10 | 2.A.10 | 11.2 |
| 44 | 37 | 2 | B | 9 | B.9 | 2.B.9 | 8.2 |
| 42 | 38 | 1 | B | 9 | B.9 | 1.B.9 | 10.6 |
| 32 | 39 | 2 | B | 10 | B.10 | 2.B.10 | 10.2 |
| 30 | 40 | 1 | B | 10 | B.10 | 1.B.10 | 8.6 |
| 28 | 41 | 2 | B | 11 | B.11 | 2.B.11 | 9.6 |
| 26 | 42 | 1 | B | 11 | B.11 | 1.B.11 | 9.1 |
| 7 | 43 | 2 | A | 11 | A.11 | 2.A.11 | 11.3 |
| 5 | 44 | 1 | A | 11 | A.11 | 1.A.11 | 8.7 |
| 57 | 45 | 1 | A | 12 | A.12 | 1.A.12 | 11.9 |
| 59 | 46 | 2 | A | 12 | A.12 | 2.A.12 | 11.2 |
| 39 | 47 | 2 | A | 13 | A.13 | 2.A.13 | 11 |
| 37 | 48 | 1 | A | 13 | A.13 | 1.A.13 | 10.7 |
| 17 | 49 | 1 | A | 14 | A.14 | 1.A.14 | 10.4 |
| 19 | 50 | 2 | A | 14 | A.14 | 2.A.14 | 8 |
| 36 | 51 | 2 | B | 12 | B.12 | 2.B.12 | 10.4 |
| 34 | 52 | 1 | B | 12 | B.12 | 1.B.12 | 9.8 |
| 16 | 53 | 2 | B | 13 | B.13 | 2.B.13 | 8.3 |
| 14 | 54 | 1 | B | 13 | B.13 | 1.B.13 | 13.3 |
| 48 | 55 | 2 | B | 14 | B.14 | 2.B.14 | 11.1 |
| 46 | 56 | 1 | B | 14 | B.14 | 1.B.14 | 9.8 |
| 4 | 57 | 2 | B | 15 | B.15 | 2.B.15 | 9.4 |
| 2 | 58 | 1 | B | 15 | B.15 | 1.B.15 | 8.3 |
| 11 | 59 | 2 | A | 15 | A.15 | 2.A.15 | 9.2 |
| 9 | 60 | 1 | A | 15 | A.15 | 1.A.15 | 12.7 |

Comment: Isn't the test a source of failure for these sampling units, contributing to non-independence of events beyond repeated measure?

Comment: Not in a meaningful way. I.e., assume failure mode is wear-out and MTTF has been measured at >100 million cycles on this test, with no appreciable difference in measurement between first and ten millionth cycle in historic testing.  So we can reasonably assume that repeat trials are giving independent results.

Comment: *"I did a pilot study using 10 specimens of widget.b (I expect the variance to be the same between widget.a and widget.b) with 2 repeat tests on each of 3 test subjects."* What sort of tests? What is a subject and what is a specimen? What is a widget?

Comment: A related question might be https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606535/optimizing-the-sample-size-number-of-individuals-versus-trials-per-individual

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus - not sure why it's relevant what type of widgets or what exactly the test is. I originally filled out the question with a dummy scenario to help define this, but I felt it was creating problems with interpretation that were distracting from the root of the question - hence the revisions.  I'd really like a generalizable approach to dealing with replicates in comparison tests, assuming all the requisite conditions are met for the selected test (whether independent or paired).

Comment: @CBRF23 it is helpful to be more specific. A test is so general. What sort of variables are the output? And 'widgets', 'subjects', 'specimens', that makes it confusing what you mean. What are the relationships between these terms. Which terms relate to random effects, which to fixed effects, what is the response variable, which variable is used in creating pairings, all such aspects are unclear when you are not specific about what your test is. Currently I am puzzled about a widget and what it means to have specimens from a group of widgets. I onlyknow widget as a small piece of software .

Comment: I agree with @SextusEmpiricus about the clarification of the definition of variables. Furthermore, "repeated measures" has a special meaning in statistical modeling, which refers to multiple measurements of the same participant that constitute longitudinal data and motivate models of mixed (i.e., random and fixed) effects. Your use of "repeated measures" does not align with this paradigm.

Comment: @MichaelLew - I've updated the question to include the data from the pilot study.  Sorry it's so late, I did not have access to the raw data over the weekend.

Answer (score 5):

Repeated testing of one widget will allow you to determine the magnitude of measurement variation (noise) and, maybe, if there are time or test-dependent changes in the performance. Those things are important, but they should typically be determined in advance of performing an experiment to determine the effect of the coating. The statistical test of the effect of coating should be based mostly on the variation between widgets rather than measurements, as the test intervention (coating) is per widget, not per measurement.

In many settings the measurement noise is small compared to the inter-widget variability, and that means that there is no substantial benefit to measuring more than once. However, if your system yields measurement noise that is too large to ignore then averaging multiple measurements is a good way to deal with it. The number of measurements to average depends on the measurement variability relative to the inter-widget variation.

In your statistical test of the coating, an independent (i.e. unpaired) t-test sounds more appropriate unless you have more relatedness within your proposed pairs than is apparent to me.

For power calculations for the effect of coating you need to first have a design in mind so that you can input the expected standard deviation into the calculation. That means that you need preliminary tests of the measurement noise and a decision on how many measurements to average. You also need either a realistic estimate of the effect of the coating to serve as the 'alternative' hypothesis size for the calculation, or an effect size that you would not want to erroneously fail to detect.

If measurements are cheap (inexpensive, easy, quick) then make lots and average them within a widget. If they are expensive then it is worth your while to perform serious preliminary characterisation of the inter-measurement variation and inter-widget variation.

Comment: Measurements are cheap, but widgets are not. Historic testing was done on coating A. Looking to see if results are meaningfully different for coating B. Improved performance in this test is allowed.  Worse performance in this test would require further testing of coating B at great expense. Historically, there is high variation between measurements - hence the desire to do multiple repeat measurements.  Not sure how to best determine how many repeat measurements are needed, or how to square that with minimum sample size. Sorry if original question was unclear.

Comment: There are dangers involved with using historical data to compare with new measurements, particularly if the measurements are less than consistent. For thinking about how many measurements to average, be aware that the benefit of each successive measurement declines in some proportion to the square root of the number of measurements.

Comment: Thanks Michael Lew! Historic data wouldn't be used for comparison, just to help with planning (i.e., historic variance used to calculate power of detection and sample size).  New widgets will be tested directly against each other for the T-Test.  Your answer helps explain some of the considerations in planning, but I'm still not sure how to determine the number of individual samples and replicates that would be needed. I'm open to other tests if a Paired-T is not appropriate (e.g., MANOVA, regression, etc.) Low part-to-part variance/high measure-to-measure variance has me thrown.

Comment: @Michael_Lew - I've revised the question and started a bounty. You've answered question 1 for me (average the repeats), but could you expand on why it's okay to compare averages of averages in a comparison test?   Re: Question 2 - you say "The number of measurements to average depends on the measurement variability relative to the inter-widget variation." How do I take my knowledge of inter-widget variation and use that to determine an appropriate number of repeat tests?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus How are these experiments paired? That is (was?) not clear to me. Using paired analyses for independent data does hurt in that it reduces the overall degrees of freedom, but I have never explored how much, and when, that matters.

Comment: @MichaelLew the experiment is not so clear to me either, but after digging into the edit history I understood it as a 'widget' that is being tested with a 'coating' resulting in some numeric outcome 'pressure' and a single widget can be tested with different coatings. Then the measurements of different coatings with the same widget can be paired/grouped.

Comment: You are right about the df change. When comparing two groups of size $n$, then the paired test will subtract the values and has only one time $n$ values to determine variance of the measurements, and the non-paired test will be able to make a more accurate estimate of the variance.

Comment: I've revised the question to generally refer to a 2-sample comparison test. I don't think the exact test is all that important, as I'm lookign for a general strategy for dealing with this problem.  @SextusEmpiricus - the link you provided above was helpful. Thank you!  Right now, I'm planning another pilot study with fewer widgets and more replicates. I think if I run `R` replicates then I can re-run the R&R study at each replicate level (i.e., `r=2, r=3, ... ,r=R`) and look for when (if) the results start to converge, and that would inform me as to how many replicates I need.

Comment: I can't provide a revised answer that will help because I do not know how best to set up the test. I could do a series of simulations with pseudo data to find the performance of various approaches, but it should probably be you doing that rather than me.

Comment: @MichaelLew - I'm happy to do the work, I don't know what needs to be done.  This is outside my wheelhouse. That's why I'm looking for guidance.  Can you elaborate on doing "a series of simulations...to find the performance of various approaches" - what kind of simulations, what kind of approaches?  I'm not sure what you're referring to. Sorry.

Comment: Start here, I guess: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135665/when-to-use-simulations

Comment: Oh, I should have added that you can ask questions about how to set up simulations in R, the free statistics package.

Comment: @MichaelLew - I'm actually taking a course in R right now :)  I also have access to MiniTab, which is the validated software used by my company.  I would be open to simulating different test setups in R, just not sure how to go about this really. I've never had a problem like this where there's so much measurement variability that needs to be dealt with.

Comment: @MichaelLew - I awarded the bounty to you for this answer. I think, through this answer and the conversations that have followed and the research this has spurred on my end, I am getting closer to answering these questions.  I may come back later and post my own answer and describe what I'm planning to do, to open my proposal up to critique and comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to compare the performance of two versions of a widget using a 2-sample comparison test. H_0 = both versions perform the same, H_1 = widget.b performs worse than widget.a.

Your hypotheses might be ill defined. They currently represent a boundary case where the null and alternative hypotheses do not complement to an entire continuous region of parameter space. A more common hypothesis definition is $H_0$: Widget B performs no worse than Widget A ($y_\text A \leqslant y_\text B$) vs. $H_1$: Widget B performs worse than Widget A ($y_\text A > y_\text B$). In this setting, we aim to find evidence that A outperforms B. It is very important to define what performance means and how it is measured. Is $y$ continuous, nonnegative, strictly positive, integer, or a duration? Response variables of different types require different modeling methods even if the hypotheses are about means.

> I have good reason to suspect there is inherent variability in the performance metric that is being measured. I want to include multiple replicates for each specimen to try to address this.

As Sextus Empiricus pointed out, you better clarify what 'widgets', 'subjects', 'specimens', 'replicates', 'repeat measures', and 'inherent variability' mean. Having variability in the response variable is natural and necessary to conduct statistical tests and analysis. Without variability, no statistical analysis is necessary.

> Question 1 - how many replicates. I'm not sure how to decide how many repeat measures (replicates) I should make with each specimen. Is 2 enough? Is 3? 10? What process (with reputable source) can I use to determine how many repeat measures I should include?

It appears that you are talking about sample-size determination. Power analysis is used to find the required sample size at given values of significance level, power, and effect size in a specific test method. The sample size to obtain ideally should be neither more nor less than this calculated requirement, as it would deflate and inflate *p* values, respectively.

> Question 2 - how to treat the replicates in the comparison test
> How does one go about incorporating replicates into the sample data for comparison testing?

Measuring the outcome multiple times on each participant can provide data to estimate within-participant variation, which makes the effect estimation more precise, standard errors smaller, and statistical tests more powerful. With longitudinal data, we need to use mixed-effect modeling. Many different experimental design can emerge: (1) one participant measured only once, (2) one participant measured multiple times but on only one version of one of the two widget, (3) one participant exposed to multiple versions of the same widget, (4) one participant exposed to both widgets, ect. With mixed-effect modeling, no need to average the responses before estimation.

> I did a pilot study using 10 specimens of widget.b (I expect the variance to be the same between widget.a and widget.b) with 2 repeat tests on each of 3 test subjects. As expected, most of the variance (92%) comes from the repeat measurement (i.e., it's inherent to the measurement), with only 8% of the variance attributable to the differences in specimens. This makes sense to me as the characteristics that define the performance of the widget in this test do not vary much from widget to widget.

In your pilot study, you had 60 rows from three participants, each of whom had 20 measurements, two per widget version. Since the ANOVA table is not built from a mixed-effect model, it may decompose the variation incorrectly and deliver a wrong impression.

> Repeat measures are cheap, but tested components cannot be placed back into inventory (i.e., it's a non-destructive test, but inventory value is reduced by testing). I have many version b widgets available and I can sample as many as I need (within reason - more than around 60 would be difficult just due to time constraints). Version a widgets are expensive and have a long lead time. I have up to 10 available to test, but would prefer to consume less if possible.

It is okay to include many versions of a widget; in fact, when using fixed-effect estimators, both the number of participants and the number of repeated measurements on each participant, which are likely done across multiple widget versions, need to be large to get consistent estimates. In a real experiment, you will likely model both widget versions and participant identities as random effects.

> My power and sample size calculations, based on the sample mean and sample s.dev from my pilot study, indicate I >90% power with n=4 and >97% power with n=5.

Your power analysis look suspicious. A sample size that small does not look right. Comparing means does not mean that *t*, *z*, or ANOVA are the best choice. You need to choose the correct model before power analysis, and that depends on the response variable type and experimental design.

Comment: "Without variability, no statistical analysis is possible." I think it's clearer to say, "Without variability, no statistical analysis is necessary." :)